# ROW (Race of work) simulation

Tags: java, performance, simulation

I wrote a ROW ([Race of work](https://gist.github.com/IlyaGazman/6208c1ac82137b409d2a2caec9b83b36)) simulation, the idea contains a mathematical bug and, I asked a question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861270/how-to-to-equally-distribute-pool-reword-in-rowrace-of-work).

I would also like to make this code more readable and, this is why I am sharing it here. Please review it and tell me how I can style it better or improve performance.

I posted it in a [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/IlyaGazman/6208c1ac82137b409d2a2caec9b83b36).

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * This is an experimental proof that in
 * <a href="https://confidence-coin.com/race-of-work-blockchain-without-forks/">ROW</a>,
 * Race of work have, your chances to mine a block are equal to your
 * computational power percentage from the entire network, or in other words, the chance to win are equally distributed.
 *
 * @author Ilya Gazman
 */
public class RowTest {

    private MessageDigest sha256;

    private RowTest() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        new RowTest().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        list.add(10);
        while (sum(list) < 100) {
            int value = random.nextInt(100 - sum(list) + 1);
            if (value == 0 || list.contains(value)) {
                continue;
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        System.out.println(sum(list) + " " + list.size());

        byte[][] players = new byte[list.size()][];
        int[] score = new int[list.size()];
        double[] reword = new double[list.size()];

        String guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        float totalGames = 1_000;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalGames; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                int player = list.get(j);
                byte[] min = null;
                for (int k = 0; k < player; k++) {
                    byte[] hash = hash(i, guid, k, player);
                    if (hash.length != 32) {
                        throw new Error("Hash error");
                    }
                    if (min == null || compare(hash, min) == -1) {
                        min = hash;
                    }
                }
                players[j] = min;
            }
            score[findWinner(players)]++;

            rewordPlayers(players, reword);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) + " won\t" + score[i] / totalGames * 100 + "%\tof the times, he earned\t" + reword[i]);
        }

        double totalReword = 0;
        for (double v : reword) {
            totalReword += v;
        }
        System.out.println("\nTotal reword " + totalReword + " / " + totalGames);
    }

    private void rewordPlayers(byte[][] players, double[] reword) {
        int rounding = BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING;
        int scale = 32;

        BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (byte[] player : players) {
            BigDecimal playerReword = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(player));
            total = total.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(playerReword, scale, rounding));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
            BigDecimal playerReword = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(players[j]));
            BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(playerReword, scale, rounding);
            BigDecimal b = a.divide(total, scale, rounding);
            reword[j] += b.doubleValue();
        }
    }

    private int findWinner(byte[][] players) {
        byte[] min = null;
        int winner = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            byte[] hash = players[i];
            if (min == null || compare(hash, min) == -1) {
                min = hash;
                winner = i;
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }

    /**
     * if a > b return 1 else if a < b return -1 else return 0
     */
    private static int compare(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        int aLength = a.length;
        int bLength = b.length;

        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0 && a[i] == 0; i--) {
            aLength--;
        }

        for (int i = b.length - 1; i >= 0 && b[i] == 0; i--) {
            bLength--;
        }

        if (aLength > bLength) {
            return 1;
        } else if (bLength > aLength) {
            return -1;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < aLength; k++) {
            int A = a[k] & 0xff;
            int B = b[k] & 0xff;
            if (A > B) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (A < B) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private byte[] hash(int i, String value, int k, int player) {
        value = i + "," + value + "," + k + "," + player;
        return sha256.digest(value.getBytes());
    }

    private int sum(Iterable<Integer> list) {
        int total = 0;
        for (Integer value : list) {
            total += value;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: "the idea contains a mathematical bug" Broken code is off-topic, does it work as intended?

Comment: @Ludisposed yeah, I plan to upgrade it in the future but for now, it's doing what it should be doing

Answer (score 1):

Very quick review here, formatting is good, so I focused on good practices, reuse of standard Java libraries (Streams), naming etc.

To have this code more organized I would embrace Objects and create a Player class, maybe a Game class. But given the short-lived nature of these objects and their quantity, it's ok not to.

Here's a reviewed (untested) code (in particular, I have no idea what it is *supposed* to do, so I don't know if it still works... but it should ^^)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

public class RowTest {

    // Make this final, because it effectively is
    private final MessageDigest sha256;

    // This is an internal constant!
    private static final int SCALE = 32;

    private RowTest() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        new RowTest().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        // Declare types of the most generic type (here, interface List is sufficient). Try to name it something meaningful ?
        List<Integer> games = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        games.add(10);
        while (sum(games) < 100) {
            int value = random.nextInt(100 - sum(games) + 1);
            // Using contains multiple times on a list of numbers? consider using a Hash structure
            if (value == 0 || games.contains(value)) {
                continue;
            }
            games.add(value);
        }
        System.out.println(sum(games) + " " + games.size());

        byte[][] players = new byte[games.size()][];
        int[] score = new int[games.size()];
        double[] reword = new double[games.size()];

        String guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        float totalGames = 1_000;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalGames; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < games.size(); j++) {
                int player = games.get(j);
                byte[] min = null;
                for (int k = 0; k < player; k++) {
                    byte[] hash = hash(i, guid, k, player);
                    if (hash.length != 32) {
                        throw new Error("Hash error");
                    }
                    if (min == null || compare(hash, min) == -1) {
                        min = hash;
                    }
                }
                players[j] = min;
            }
            // Split these operations. For debugging, it'll be easier to follow! It's bad practice to russian-doll method calls with array access and unary operations. Method calls alone might pass.
            final int winner = findWinner(players);
            score[winner]++;

            rewordPlayers(players, reword);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(games.get(i) + " won\t" + score[i] / totalGames * 100 + "%\tof the times, he earned\t" + reword[i]);
        }

        // Use streams everywhere! they are good for you
        double totalReword = Arrays.stream(reword).sum();

        System.out.println("\nTotal reword " + totalReword + " / " + totalGames);
    }

    private void rewordPlayers(byte[][] players, double[] reword) {
        // No need to store this locally, especially this the var name doesn't mentions which rounding is done
        // int rounding = BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING;


        // Guess what? we can stream this :)
        BigDecimal total = Arrays.stream(players) // Streaming all players
                .map(RowTest::dividePlayer) // calculating the inverse
                .reduce(BigDecimal::add)// adding all
                .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO); // If no player, then zero

        for (int j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
            BigDecimal a = dividePlayer(players[j]);
            BigDecimal b = a.divide(total, SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
            reword[j] += b.doubleValue();
        }
    }

    // For easier reading, i'm extracting this code to reduce redundancy
    private static BigDecimal dividePlayer(byte[] player) {
        BigDecimal playerReword = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(player));
        return BigDecimal.ONE.divide(playerReword, SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
    }


    // Make everything you can 'static', makes it easy to see it doesn't change object state
    private static int findWinner(byte[][] players) {
        return IntStream.range(0, players.length)// Browse all players
                        .reduce((i, j) -> compare(players[i], players[j]) < 0 ? i : j)// For any two, pick index of the lowest
                        .orElse(-1); // Default value
    }

    /**
     * if a > b return 1 else if a < b return -1 else return 0
     */
    private static int compare(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        int aLength = a.length;
        int bLength = b.length;

        // More concise.
        // Also you're just looking for the longest streak of '0' at the end of the byte.
        // A 'while' loop is much more useful and shows that the loop is *supposed* to be interrupted.
        // A 'for' loop is assumed to (generally) span the entire range regardless.
        while (aLength >= 0 && a[aLength] == 0) {
            aLength--;
        }
        while (bLength >= 0 && b[bLength] == 0) {
            bLength--;
        }

        // Why not just return aLength - bLength ? compare can return any number. Only its sign matter.
        if (aLength > bLength) {
            return 1;
        } else if (bLength > aLength) {
            return -1;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < aLength; k++) {
            // avoiding having variables with only differing capitalization!
            int maskedA = a[k] & 0xff;
            int maskedB = b[k] & 0xff;
            // Why not just return maskedA - maskedB ? compare can return any number. Only its sign matter.
            if (maskedA > maskedB) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (maskedA < maskedB) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private byte[] hash(int i, String value, int k, int player) {
        // Never reassign a reference given to you in input!
        String appended = i + "," + value + "," + k + "," + player;
        return sha256.digest(appended.getBytes());
    }

    // Again, make this static!
    private static int sum(List<Integer> list) {
        // can be easily replaced with streams, for better performance etc.
        return list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
    }
}
```